# How can I deploy my machine gun without any enemies around?

Tags: company-of-heroes-2

How can I tell my machine gunners to move to a point and deploy their machine guns (preferably with some directional control)? Usually they just walk to a point, wait till they see an enemy, start deploying in that direction, then find out that by the time they finish deploying the enemy is on the other side and they need to redeploy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you have your weapons team selected, right click in the location you want them to setup and while holding the right click down, drag in the direction you want them to face. They will then go to this location and setup as soon as you release the button.

The arc of fire of the unit should be displayed while you hold the mouse down.